# How does one format a URL inside of a Controller in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

It would be nice to be able to format a url in a portable way inside of a controller, for example for a JSON response. Is there an easy way to do this without creating an instance of `Zend_View` first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If saying "format URL" you meaning create an url from params, `url` view helper is you answer. You use it in controller the same way as in view and don't need to create new `Zend_View` instance - if you're using view renderer you have your helper in `$this->view`. So

```
//in view
$this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'default'));

//in controller
$this->view->url(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'default'));
```

But if you look into code of `url` view helper, you'll see, that it's using router object to assemble routes/url/. So all you need is router object, which you can obtain in several ways, some of them:

```
//in controller
$router = $this->getFrontController()->getRouter();
//anywhere
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();
//and then
$router->assemble(array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'default'));
```

You can also use HelperBroker, retrieve viewRenderer from there, retrieve a view and run helper method.

Answer (score 2):

Several thoughts here:

1. Even if you are generating a JSON response, you can still use the view object and view-scripts via the [ContextSwitch and AjaxContext](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch) action helpers.
2. Even if you don't use a view-script for your response, you have probably already instantiated the view back at Bootstrap. So in the controller you wouldn't actually be *creating* the view as much as *accessing* it. So no additional overhead there.
3. If by "portable" you mean "cross-project", then maybe an action-helper? Drop it into another project, configure helper paths, and you're good to go. If by "portable" you mean "more aware of your application's routing", then you're probably stuck using the view object.